# XCode 5: Documentation Viewer only shows "What's New in Xcode"

Tags: xcode5

When I select 'Help->Documentation and API Reference' in XCode 5, the only content that shows up in the doc viewer window is the "What's new in Xcode" notes. I can't see any way to browse or load any actual API documentation content.

I checked the ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets folder and verified that the docs sets are there for iOS5 - iOS7. After re-installing XCode 4.6.3 I also verified the documentation content can be seen in the old Organizer Help.

I'd rather not keep XCode 4 around just to read docs offline; how can I force XCode 5 to load the local documentation sets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

Seems like searching for documentation is the only option. The right sidebar is an index only applicable to the current document (in this case "What's new in Xcode"). The documentation is there and visible to Xcode 5, but it doesn't appear to have exposed a way to browse them directly.

Long answer:

It appears to me that you have to search for the documentation rather than being able to browse it. For instance, with the default search settings (the magnifying glass on "Automatic"), searching for "Mountain Lion" (without highlighting an autocomplete entry) will bring up a search page, and under SDK Guides will be the entry "OS X Mountain Lion v10.8". The right sidebar will turn into a browser for the "What's New in OS X" category. This appears to be the only way to "browse" the documentation. Even using View->Show Tab Bar and opening a new tab only opens a blank page.

The Apple Developer page ["New Features in Xcode 5"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012953-SW29) has information on the new Documentation viewer. The description sounds similar to how the online library works, where if the current document has multiple sections, it will show you the table of contents for the document currently open. For instance, the page I linked is part of a document "What's new in Xcode". There is no indication, both from the linked page and from looking at the application, that there is a way to browse categories like in Xcode 4.

The [Xcode 5 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW241) do say that you can store documentation in the DocSets folder, just as before.

The online Developer Libraries still have a minimal amount of navigation. In terms of offline docs, Apple's provided .docset files have the same interface stored inside at Show Package Contents -> Contents/Resources/Documentation/navigation/index.html. If you use the "Share" button on the Xcode Documentation window to open the page in a web browser (I had much better luck with Safari than Chrome 31), you can click on the Mac/iOS Developer Library link in the top left corner of the webpage. In Safari, this opens a Finder window located in one of the DocSets in the DocSet folder. You can then go to the navigation folder and open index.html (Safari loaded this, while Chrome sat and spun) to get the same interface as the online libraries.

Hopefully the old category browsing gets reimplemented (or someone rediscovers how to view it). In the meantime it may help to start making and using bookmarks, which are the grey flags next to article titles/sections, and browse them using the left sidebar of the Documentation window. The main project window's right sidebar also has a Quick Help (the box with wavy lines) which may be of some use, with the Features in Xcode 5 saying that it can display Doxygen or HeaderDoc style documentation comments from your code.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the only way to browse/view offline docs without keeping older versions of XCode or using 3rd party apps.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried Dash...? This will let you read documentation offline and you download the Mac / iOS doc-sets : http://kapeli.com/dash

FYI I am not the developer, just a user.

Comment: Amazing app! Highly recommended.

Comment: Looks like a good app, but given its cost as a paid app, it's overkill for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to go the the Settings-Menu (Xcode>Preferences...), to the tab Downloads. There you can choose the Documentations you want (iOS, Xcode, OSX, ...)

Answer (score 1):

It's disappointing that the Treeviewer seems to have disappeared as I used to like browsing through all the topics and stumble upon something interesting.

The closest workaround - of sorts - I came to (outside the suggestion above of browsing the docsets directly in safari, which can work if you setup a bookmark on safari) was to select an extremely small search term and choose "Show All Results". You still don;t get everything, but it's better than nothing.

I hope they bring it back, but maybe the logic is that they are trying to direct people to the docs on the site.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with some unrelated issues (creating my own documentation and actually check it out on Xcode), so I ended up in this question and messing with the documentation viewer.

It might be something new in my Xcode version, or I might be just misunderstanding what you want but I can access the tree structure of the documentation by pressing this button:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't bothered with the Xcode 5 document viewer since I posted the original question. I checked it out and looks like they made it semi-useful again in the latest version. Apple seems intent on re-writing their apps from scratch and releasing with large chunks of missing features (e.g. the latest version of iWork).